# Error while generating a password for my number when using Password generated software for whatsapp API

Tags: c#, asp.net, whatsapp

https://github.com/mgp25/WART

I have downloaded the Password generator from this Link.

But i am getting an error during Generation like this using my Number.

```
  **Could not request code using either SMS or voice**

  `SMS: {"status":"fail","reason":"bad_token"}`

  `Voice: {"status":"fail","reason":"bad_token"}`
```

I searched online and found this link

http://www.17educations.com/whatsapp/how-to-get-whatsapp-id-and-password/

Even then I am getting same error.

I don't know why? Is there any other way to generate password?

Comment: This is most likely due to a change on WhatsApp side in the recent months, seeing that the the project hasn't been updated for a while.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Going through their code you'll notice the example website they show now leads to a parked-domain, and their last commit was two years ago. WhatsApp has gone through many changes in this time and as such is unlikely to still work.

A lot more information can be found about tokens by the same author on another repository they made [here](https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API/wiki/WhatsApp-Registration-Flow) and [here](https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API/wiki/Token-Generation).

I don't understand your question quite enough to say for sure, but my guess is that you're trying to use the WhatsApp API for something and trying to get a password to use with it.

Modern secure online APIs have moved to using "tokens" rather than "passwords" now. Tokens can be roughly summarised as a username and a password combined into one long piece of text. You have to first generate one of these by providing WhatsApp with your username and password, and then getting a token back, and then using the token as part of the call to the API.

I hope some of that helps, feel free to comment if I missed the mark.